# Take complete backup of table with index and keys in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, production-environment

I have a table (i.e. `tbl_test`) with 46 index and 42 keys.

I have taken backup via this command:

```
select *  
into tbl_test_bkp_18112019 
from tbl_test
```

But it is unable to copy index and keys in the backup table. I want to take a complete backup of the table with index and keys. Please suggest how.

Comment: why don't you do a `Database Backup` instead ?

Comment: @Squirrel, seriously? and then what, edit the backup by hand  to exclude everything else? Not to mention the cost.  OP needs DDL and load in insert format. Third party tools can do this.

Answer (score 1):

`Select * into` - Does not copy indexes, constraints, etc.

You should generate a script from SQL server management studio by right-clicking on the desired table -> Script table as -> create to -> New query windows.

Change the table name as needed and run the script.

This will create a new table with the same structure, indexes, constraints, etc.

If you need data as well then you can insert from the orignal table to this new table using insert command

```
Insert newtablename select columns from oldtablename
```

Comment: Thanks mukesh for your support. table having 1crore data.may i know how much time will take for this activity to genereate scripts and execute and to insert data from original table.

Comment: the table creation will be quick as it is just a schema of the table. data insertion will take time, time taken will depend on many factors hardware configuration, no of columns in a table, constraint, indexes etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try Task > Generate Script and select only table with data and check in SQL Management Studio